# dataGridView is not showing new tuples added to Access Database

Tags: c#, forms, ms-access, datagridview

I just made a simple C#.NET windows form and made its connection with Microsoft Access. Thereafter, I dragges dataGridView from data source and it's working perfectly fine until I add new rows/tuples into my Access database, as it does not show these new tuples/rows

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=your .mdb file;";
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM Authors";
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connetionString);
            OleDbDataAdapter dataadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            connection.Open();
            dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Authors_table");
            connection.Close();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
            dataGridView1.DataMember = "Authors_table";
        }
    }
}
```